# Android Function testing report generate using Appium + Python

Tags: python, appium, functional, test-report

I am currently working on a mobile application with appium with python. There are a  lot of options for every file selection in that. Currently checking if processing all the types of files are possible in that. So, there are a lot of combinations for each file. I successfully managed to access through all of the combinations using nested loops and some basic algorithms. Currently generating the combinations and their results in a csv sheet through JSON format. I need some help about how can I generate good test report in a professional way for each of these combination.

Comment: Who will read the test report? What they want to know? How will that information help them in their decision making? A report just for the sake of reporting is a waste of time and effort. I'm not saying your report is a waste of time, but you have not mentioned what good means to you.

Comment: Mainly the developers and the manual testers. They want to know how the application performs for different type of inputs. If something is unusual with any specific combination. Although the JSON format is easily understood by the devs. But the manual testers of the team wont be able to understand it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python try the [pytest output](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/output.html#creating-junitxml-format-files)

```
$ py.test sample_tests.py --junitxml=C:\path\to\out_report.xml
```

It outputs in JUNIT (XML) format and there are many parsers and CI/CD plugins to present the results. See one such [example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml) for Azure DevOps.